# Adding the total cost of a shopping cart

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am trying to add up the total price each time a new item is added to the cart. I know the code can be written cleaner and more complex but I have been asked to use this format. With my current code the total stays at 0. My buttons are working fine.

```
var price = 0;
var totalPrice = 0;

var cartSummary = "";

price = product1.price;
cartSummary += product1.name + " €" + product1.price + "<br>";
totalPrice += product1.price;
document.getElementById("cart").innerHTML = cartSummary;
```

Comment: Can you please post the price function? And product1?

Comment: you have stored your total value in `totalPrice`. but I think you haven't used it in html file to print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = totalPrice;`

I forgot to add this line in the function so it was not updating in HTML
Thanks for the help regardless

Answer (score 0):

Make the function return the value you want to add and outside the function add the value:

```
function addValue(product1) {
    price = product1.price;
    cartSummary += product1.name + " €" + product1.price + "<br>";
    document.getElementById("cart").innerHTML = cartSummary;
    return product1.price;
}

totalPrice += addValue(product1);
```

Comment: Will this be suitable for multiple products ? It adds fine in console but it does not seem to refresh the total if that is any help

Comment: Based on the fact that JS works by-ref, you can just send the data you want to change to the function and it will change it. (Send the `totalPrice` and `cartSummary`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the following changes to your code:

```
cartSummary += product1.name + " €" + product1.price + "<br>"; becomes `cartSummary = product1.name + " €" + product1.price + "<br>";`
```

And `totalPrice += product1.price;` becomes `totalPrice += number(product1.price);`